# Hide a sailsjs blueprint route

Tags: routes, sails.js

I'm using sailsjs to implement an node service.

I added some models controllers and routes with blueprints.
But I would like to hide some routes, not expose them.
Is there any way to do this cleanly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you mean routes calls "shadow" that implements blueprints by default when you start a project in sails, this can be disabled going to config/blueprints.js, and you can set action to false. MOre information here:
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-blueprints
Then you could create your own actions in a given Controller, and link from the route.js
Regards.